# What does the Cognito Forms "entry limit" cover?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is the entry limit on logins/plans based on numbers per form, or total numbers across all forms?

Answer (score 1):

The entry limit in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) is based on the number of **new entries** created across **all forms each month**, not based on the total number of entries.