# Is there a maximum number of entries for a Cognito Form?

Tags: cognito-forms

We are about to use Cognito Forms in our next enrollment, but we would like to know if there is a maximum number of entries?

Comment: Note that this is not Cognito Forms support. Please take the [tour] to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 1):

There are monthly entries limits for all except Enterprise accounts, but they're based on account, not form.

Per the [pricing page](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing):

> - Free: 500 entries per month
> - Pro ($10/mo): 2,000/mo
> - Team ($24/mo): 10,000/mo
> - Enterprise ($99/mo): Unlimited

See also: [What does the Cognito Forms "entry limit" cover?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87702/354)